# Error al descargar archivos zip c# restsharp

Tags: c#, api, csv, zip

Tengo una api rest que me permite descargar a través de una URL registros de cada mes, el mes anterior al actual lo presenta en un fichero .csv y los demás en formato zip, la estructura de la URL es para el mes anterior al actual:

- [https://URL.com/id/reading-AñoMes.csv](https://URL.com/id/reading-A%C3%B1oMes.csv)

Y para los meses anteriores:

- [https://URL.com/id/reading-AñoMes.zip](https://URL.com/id/reading-A%C3%B1oMes.zip)

Tengo un ciclo que recorre y va modificando el año y haciendo la respectiva petición a la API, el mes anterior que es en formato csv lo descargo de forma correcta, pero los archivos zip me descargan de forma errónea, bajan con el nombre que les coloco, pero todos pesan 1kb y obviamente al abrir tiran error, ¿alguien podría decirme cual es el error? este es mi código:

```
for (int i = 0; i < totalMonths; i++)
{
    if (i==0)
    {
        RestClient clientMa;

        if ((i + 1) > 9)
        {
            clientMa = new RestClient("https://URL.com/" + networkId + "/files/csv/vw/" + cod + "-readings-" + añoAct + "-" + (mesAct - 1) + ".csv");
        }
        else
        {
            clientMa = new RestClient("https://url.com/" + networkId + "/files/csv/vw/" + cod + "-readings-" + añoAct + "-" + "0"+(mesAct - 1) + ".csv");
        }
        var requestMa = new RestRequest(Method.GET);
        requestMa.AddHeader("Cache-Control", "no-cache");
        requestMa.AddHeader("Authorization", "Basic XXXXXX");
        if ((i + 1) > 9)
        {
            clientMa.DownloadData(requestMa).SaveAs(cod + "-readings-" + añoAct + "-" +(mesAct - 1) + ".csv");
        }
        else
        {
            clientMa.DownloadData(requestMa).SaveAs(cod + "-readings-" + añoAct + "-" + "0" + (mesAct - 1) + ".csv");
        }
    }
    else
    {
        RestClient client;
        RestRequest request;

        if ((i + 1) > 9)
        {
            client = new RestClient("https://url.com/" + networkId + "/files/csv/vw/" + cod + "-readings-" + añoAct + "-" + (mesAct - (i-2)) + ".zip");
            client.Authenticator = new HttpBasicAuthenticator(username, password);
            request = new RestRequest(Method.GET);
            client.DownloadData(request).SaveAs(cod + "-readings-" + añoAct + "-" +(mesAct - 1) + ".zip");
        }
        else
        {
            client = new RestClient("https://url.com/" + networkId + "/files/csv/vw/" + cod + "-readings-" + añoAct + "-" + "0" + (mesAct - 1) + ".zip");
            client.Authenticator = new HttpBasicAuthenticator(username, password);
            request = new RestRequest(Method.GET);
            client.DownloadData(request).SaveAs(cod + "-readings-" + añoAct + "-" + "0" + (mesAct - (i - 2)) + ".zip");
        }
    }
}
```

Como repito el fichero csv se descarga de forma correctamente, pero me es imposible descargar los anteriores en .zip.

Comment: No se si es el problema, pero cuando envias los `.zip` no estás añadiendo los headers al `RestClient`

Comment: Cambie el client.Authenticator = new HttpBasicAuthenticator(username, password); por requestMa.AddHeader("Authorization", "Basic XXXXXX"); por  y asi funciono, pero lo raro es que deberia funcionar con el client.Authenticator, ya que agragandole el header de la primera forma no es dinamico.

Comment: No controlo suficiente de restsharp para darte una respuesta la verdad. Podría ser tambien el `("Cache-Control", "no-cache");`, aunque por lo que dices parece ser un problema de permiso, no debe poder acceder usando el `client.Authenticator`.A ver si alguien que sepa mas puede darte una explicación.

Comment: Muchas gracias, tu respuesta fue de mucha ayuda.

Comment: @Pikoh por favor publica tu comentario como respuesta para que el OP pueda aceptarla. Saludos.

Comment: @MauricioAriasOlave no tengo muy claro que de para una respuesta válida y completa. Fue una sugerencia que hice sin estar muy seguro, y no tengo claro el porqué...